# can webworkers be used to make timing more accurate

Tags: javascript, html, animation, settimeout, web-worker

If you want to animation this commonly involves calling settimeout or setinterval. The event then joins the other events in the event queuing system and the event may get delayed from the time set when you called the settimeout due to the application GUI processing other events like canvas mouse movements. However what if you set up the animation loop in a webworker? that will not be influenced by GUI events and can accurately call the animation function in the main thread (using postmessage) at the precise time interval set in the function call. Seems ok in theory at least, but would it really work?

Comment: this is an interesting approach

http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-accurate-timers-in-javascript/ although you still will have the individual incorrect time, subsequent events adjust to fire more in less on time with the interval

Answer (score 3):

> However what if you set up the animation loop in a webworker?

Same problem: The event coming from the web worker that tells you it's time to do something joins the same task queue that `setTimeout` or `setInterval`'s tasks join.

You might get better results from [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) rather than `setTimeout`/`setInterval`, as its express purpose is to increase the synchronization of your code with the browser's display refresh cycle.

Comment: I am more concerned with accurate audio sounds, say if you want to play a sound in exactly 5 seconds. Webaudio has its own clock for sound events that works pretty well and seems independant of the main event queue, but I want to use a simpler sound api that will translate to other platforms  (phonegap or libGDX sound api) and they only seem to offer a play now functionality

Comment: Actually maybe the answer to correct timing lies with the webaudio NoteOn function. How is it possible that this function can schedule a sound event to be played exactly so many milliseconds in the future? If this functionality could be extracted from the API then it would be possible to create a truly accurate setInterval function for animation or other purposes. It seems to only have the system clock to work with. Maybe it does some kind of forecasting based on sampling the system clock, however to guarantee accuracy?.

Comment: If you're doing audio, [this blog post](https://meowni.ca/posts/metronomes/) shows webworkers can be used for improving timing.